# Export Leaflet map in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I want to save map leaflet data on database so
how can I get the json data from leaflet map in react js ? at least to console.log them

Comment: Which data do you want ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.